# SNMP - how to write mib module?

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, mib, oid

I want to read data from my sensors on 2 devices with SNMP(net-SNMP).
Do I have to write my own mib code for this?
I want to read the sensor data on these two devices via a manager code.
what do I need to do about this?

Answer (score 0):

You should first check if a MIB for your device already exists: go check to [this site](https://bestmonitoringtools.com/mibdb/mibdb_search.php?all=1).

You should then see if you need a SNMP Subagent: if you want to extend your SNMP Master Agent with MIBs different from the default ones (like system or network), you should use a Subagent (see [here](https://vincent.bernat.ch/en/blog/2012-extending-netsnmp) on how to extend a Master Agent with a Subagent; usually, this is performed through AgentX protocol).

You may run the entire echosystem on your localhost and see first if all the components are up and operative: in this phase, you may mimic your sensors by returning hard-coded values to your Subagent.